# Multiple image upload in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading

I want to upload multiple images using wordpress.

Here is my code which is using to single upload

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) 

 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo'];

$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );

$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );


  if ( $movefile ) {

    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

    var_dump( $movefile);

   }

 else {

    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";

   }
```

How I can upload multiple images using wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement like this:

```
 $files = $_FILES['photo'];
    foreach ($files['photo'] as $key => $value) {
      if ($files['name'][$key]) {
        $file = array(
          'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
          'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
          'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
          'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
          'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
        );
        wp_handle_upload($file);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you're trying to do easier by using the native WordPress Media Uploader.

I had a good resource bookmarked at one point but can't seem to find it. I ran into a situation a few months ago that required the same thing. This is what I ended up doing:

Loading the WordPress image scripts into the beginning of my PHP script:

`require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );`

Then you can call the uploader on element click using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Define a variable to be used to store the frame data
  var file_frame;
  var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
  var set_to_post_id = 999; // Set this

  $('#upload_button').live('click', function( event ){

    element = $(this);

    event.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if (file_frame) {
      // Set the post ID to what we want
      file_frame.uploader.uploader.param('post_id', set_to_post_id);
      // Open frame
      file_frame.open();
      return;
    } else {
      // Set the wp.media post id so the uploader grabs the ID we want when initialised
      wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: $(this).data('uploader_title'),
      button: {
        text: $(this).data('uploader_button_text'),
      },
      multiple: true  // Set to false to allow only one file to be selected
    });

    // When an image(s) have been selected, run a callback.
    file_frame.on('select', function() {

      // Do something if necessary
        function_to_fire();

    });

    // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();
  });

});
```

There is an `attachment` object passed to the callback function which will contain all of the IDs and such for the attachments uploaded.

The `set_to_post_id` is the id of the post/page you want to "attach" the media to. If you're not trying to attach them to a post, you shouldn't need to worry about this and some of the above code will not apply.